# How to know if a Firebird 2.0 database is being accessed?

Tags: firebird

I know that using Firebird 2.5+ I can check if there are users accessing my database using SQL, but unfortunately, Firebird 2.0 doesn't have this feature. Yes, I know it's an old version, but it's a legacy software and I'm not allowed to upgrade this in a short time... :(

I need to know if someone is connected to my 2.0 Firebird database, due to a process I'll run:

1. Block connections to DB (but **ONLY** if no one is connected)
2. Run my process
3. Allow users to reconnect again

I can start my process only when there are no users connected.

My database is part of a client/server system (no Web).

Any hints?

Comment: upgrade to FB 2.1, they are largely compatible and monitor tables are since 2.1

Comment: Upgrading would a good thing, but as I said on my question, I'm not allowed to do this at this time. Our software is distributed to a lot of users and installed locally by them. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Firebird 2.0 has been end-of-life since 2012, 2.1 since 2014 and 2.5 since 2019. You really need to start upgrading. Especially as there are several security related bugs that weren't fixed in versions below 2.5. The step from 2.0 to 2.5 isn't that big. From 2.5 to 3.0 may be more involved though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wish I could upgrade FB. If fact, we'll redesign our software, but this will take something like 2 years to delivery. What I need at this moment is just keep our software running making only mandatory modifications.

Comment: Why do you need this exclusive access, and can't you achieve this by using a transaction with snapshot table stability with table reservation instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not an elegant way, but works...

1. I try to rename the database file.
2. If there is someone accessing the database, the rename operation will give me
   an exception, saying that the file is in use by some process.
3. If rename succeeds, new users will not be able to access the database
   anymore (the connection string used by my systems is not changed).
4. I run the exclusive process I have to.
5. Rename the database file to its original name, allowing new users to
   connect again.

I post my solution in the hope that helps someone facing a similar problem.

Our new version of the product will probably a Web application and the database was not choosen yet, but certainly will no be Firebird.

Thanks to all that tried to give me an answer.

Comment: Be aware that this only works properly on Windows. On Linux and others it is possible to rename files that are in use. Old filehandles will continue to work. It might be better to use gfix to shutdown the database instead.

Comment: 1-3 and 5 can be done in Firebird native way - bringing database into shutdown single-user mode, and then back to online mode. That way you would not have to give your applications knowledge of file locations (de-coupling) and file access rights. File renaming approach is less flexible and more fragile.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's only Windows. Thanks God that this version if our product is exclusively used in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> -at[tach] : this parameter prevents any new connections to the database from being made with the exception of the SYSDBA and the database owner. The shutdown will fail if **there are any sessions connected after the timeout** period has expired. It makes no difference if those connected sessions belong to the SYSDBA, the database owner or any other user. Any connections remaining will terminate the shutdown with the following details:

https://firebirdsql.org/manual/gfix-dbstartstop.html

There is also Services API to do it so your database access library should expose the shutdown function. Specify a short shutdown, and if it failed - then there were some users. If it succeeded - now you can go on with maintenance, having a warranty client applications will not be able to connect.

---

Alternatively you can upgrade Firebird 2.0 -> 2.1 which is more close to 2.0 than 2.5 but already have Monitoring Tables implemented.
However this your approach has one weak point - race conditions. Using M.T. you envision your work as following:

1. Keep querying M.T. (which slows down server work significantly) until there are no other connections.
2. start maintenance work, that would fail if other connections are active
3. complete maintenance work

Problem is, that even after at step 1 you gained "no other connection" state, it does not mean that between steps 1 and 2, and especially between steps 2 and 3 now new connections would be made.

Even if you made your checks and ensure #1 condition, when you would go on with maintenance there would be some new user connected back and working now. Not every time of course, but as time goes by it will eventually happen one day.

---

But there is yet one more good thing in FB 2.1 - database-level triggers.

> c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\doc\sql.extensions\README.db_triggers.txt

You can create a regular "all_current_connections" table, using `on connect` and `on disconnect` triggers to keep it up to date.
You perhaps would also have to add some logic to your applications, so they would update that table with your internal application ID, to tell main workflow apps/connections from servicing utilities. However it is also possible that mere `CURRENT_USER` and `CURRENT_CONNECTION` pair, which the trigger knows and can store to the table, would be enough for that table, if you can infer kind of application from mere user name.

Then `on disconnect` trigger might be checking whether all "main workflow" apps disconnected and `POST_EVENT` to notify servicing utilities. However those utilities **would still have to `shutdown` the database** first, anyway.

Comment: Going from 2.0 to 2.5 should not be a major leap either, if I recall correctly.

Comment: As I said in my question, I'm not allowed to upgrade FB at this time. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there are reportedly some subtle changes in ODs like identifier name lengths and something, that albeit 2.5 can work wit h2.0 and 2.1 ODS witout changing it, it is not always that this database the nagain can be used by FB 2.0/2.1. Did not experienced it myself, so can not give more details

Comment: @NiloPaim then make software register on connect and de-register on disconnect. To distribute your new app to users you would still need to make new version upgrade.

Comment: 2.0 to 2.1 is already an ODS upgrade though. And the identifier length didn't actually change (it was always 31 bytes). I think the only thing that changed was an error in the API that suggested that identifiers were 31 characters in UNICODE_FSS as opposed to 31 bytes in UNICODE_FSS.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel upgrade to 2.5 ODS potentially has issue with non-Latin string literals in PSQL, however what I was talking about is using FB2.5 to work with 2.0 ODS and 2.1 ODS. In paper it keeps compatibility of those database files with their "native" prior Firebird versions. But it seems devils is in details and sometimes mere work in FB 2.5 with pre-2.5 ODS files somehow "taints" them that they become problematic to pre-2.5 server. Notice, not conversion w. B/R cycle, but mere operating older database files by 2.5 server

Answer (score 2):

You can shut down the database using gfix. The gfix tool will try to shutdown the database and if connections still exist after a timeout, the shutdown will fail.

For example, use:

```
gfix -shut -attach 5 <your-database>
```

This will:

1. prevent new connection being created,
2. wait 5 seconds for the existing connections to end,
3. if after 5 seconds there are still active connections the shutdown will abort,
4. otherwise, after 5 seconds the database will be shut down.

After shutdown, only SYSDBA or the database owner can create a connection to the database. This is only a viable option if your application it self doesn't use SYSDBA or the database owner account.

You bring the database back online using:

```
gfix -online <your-database>
```

For more information, see also [Gfix - Database Housekeeping: Database Startup and Shutdown](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gfix/firebird-gfix.html#gfix-dbstartstop)

Comment: how can he programmatically check if it failed or not? with API call it would be more simple, but we do not know his library...

Comment: @Arioch'The Gfix returns an error message if it failed to shutdown. I assume it also returns an error level, but I haven't checked that. You can also do this using the services API, and that will return an error response as well.

Comment: Intercepting output and parsing is a task of its own, and error-codes do not seem to be reliable thing in FB utilities (failed GBAK returns Success error code interpreting it as "successfully finished Services API session").  I also wonder if "single-connection mode" was already in FB 2.0 or introduced later, to exactly avoid the risk of race conditions secondary connections being made before maintenance is over.

Comment: @Arioch'The The single connection mode was introduced in Firebird 2, see "New Startup and Shutdown States in Firebird 2.0" in the gfix documentation I linked. And in any case, nothing in the question suggests that this need to be done programmatically.

Comment: Then perhaps it would make sense if you would modify the command you suggest to enforce that mode?  Or at least offer that as an option. Indeed, we do not know what his "maintenance" include, can it work with one connection nor needs more... Maybe ugly renaming is indeed the only way to prevent race conditions, but still better be done after bringing the database into full offline mode.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Gfix returns an error message, that must be parsed to know what happened. The error level returned by Gfix is always 0, indicating complete running, and not the success of the operation that is executed.

Comment: @Arioch'The The "ugly" renaming was the only way I found. I cannot shutdown FB, ´cause my maintenance includes, among other things, ALTER some tables and columns.

Comment: @NiloPaim After shutting down a database, the database owner and sysdba can still access it.

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm not recommending to shut down the database to perform renaming. I'm suggesting to shut down the database to perform the maintenance.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel here is you now misreading or so it seems. For renaming - or any other file-level rather than SQL-level operations - I suggest shutting down Firebird SERVICE not the database. Shutting down the database is of course done instead of renaming. Or, rather, renaming is a weird substitute for shutting down a database (and NOT the service) when for some reason things can not be done intended way.

Comment: @NiloPaim `Gfix returns an error message, that must be parsed to know what happened. The error level returned by Gfix is always 0` - GFIX here invokes the FB Service API that your program can invoke itself. You would have to consult your Firebird connection library to see how services like validation and backup/restore and querying information are implemented. You may cross-check that lib sources with IB6 API Guide at https://firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ then you may look into side channels how to augment that call with FB2 introduced extended database (not server) shutdown modes.